# How to find the class of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
 x^3\sin(\frac{1}{x}); & \text{ if, } x \neq 0 \\
 0; & \text{ $x=0$ }
\end{cases}$$

How do I find the greatest value of n such that $f \in C^n ([-1,1])$?

I know to find n, I must find the greatest n such that $f^{(n)}(x)$ is differentiable in the interval $[-1,1]$. But how do I prove its differentiability?

Comment: High level comment, the way to approach this is to engage with equations for the derivative of $f$, giving special attention to $0$ where the piecewise nature of the definition of $f$ requires further analysis as to differentiability. I don't see any simpler way of just "seeing" what $n$ is going to be. I mean, actually I do, but if someone asked me to explain where $n$ was coming from, I'd definitely be running through some formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check if $f^{(n)}$ is continuous $n$ by $n$.

Start with $n=0$.

The function is continuous because
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^3 \sin{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)} = \lim_{x \to 0^-} x^3 \sin{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)}=0.$$

For $n=1$,
$f'(x) = \begin{cases} -x \cos{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)} + 3x^2 \sin{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)} , & \text{ if } x \neq 0\\
0, & \text{ if } x = 0
\end{cases}$
is continuous because
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} -x \cos{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)} + 3x^2 \sin{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)} = \lim_{ x \to 0^-} -x \cos{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)} + 3x^2 \sin{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)} = 0.$$
For $n = 2$,
$f''(x) = \begin{cases} -4 \cos{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)} - \tfrac{1}{x}\sin{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)}+6x\sin{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)} , & \text{ if } x \neq 0\\ 
0, & \text{ if } x = 0
\end{cases}$ is not continuous because
$$\lim_{ x \to 0}-4 \cos{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)} - \tfrac{1}{x}\sin{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)}+6x\sin{\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)}$$ does not exist.

Thus the greatest $n$ for which $f \in C^n([-1,1])$ is $n=1$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Wanted to check, is there a typo in the 1st derivative? Should it be $3x^2$ instead?

Comment: Yes, there is a typo, I'm going to correct it.

Comment: Okay. Thank you, will wait for the update.

Answer (score 1):

Check that $f'(0)=0$ and $f'(x)=3x^2\sin (1/x) - x\cos (1/x)$ if $x\ne 0.$ It follows that $f'$ is continuous everywhere.

However, for $x\ne 0,$

$$\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x-0} = 3x\sin (1/x) - \cos (1/x).$$

As $x\to 0,$ the first term on the right $\to 0.$ But $\cos(1/x)$ has no limit as $x\to 0.$ Therefore $f''(0)$ does not exist. It follows that $n=1$ is the answer to the problem.